# What is the problem with my differential equation solver I made using an op-amp in PSpice?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, control-system

I designed a differential equation solver using an op-amp in PSpice, but the output is not what I expected. According to the equation, its transfer function poles are (-3,-2) with no complex part. So, its output should be overdamped but it is not. What could be the problem?

[image]

[image: i use lm741]

[image]

Comment: The outer loop contains 4 inverting opamps which means: Positive feedback (instability). It must be an uneven number.

Comment: Also try choosing a different opamp. Anything is better than 741.

Comment: The poles are -1 and -2